# Multi-device alarm clock

Tags: cross-platform, alarm-clock

I'd like to find an alarm clock/timer app that works on multiple devices.

I'd like to just set a timer for 6 hours just before sleeping, after which my iPad, Android phone and laptop (Windows) should yell bloody murder. Bonus if it makes sure I'm awake using some form of torture.

What I've tried:

- **Timely**, but the free version seems buggy and too easy to mute in my early morning haze.
- **Google Calendar**, but it requires too many clicks/taps to configure. I'm looking to have to just enter a number and click/tap and it should behave like an alarm. Google Calendar does something like a notify/short beep by default.

Comment: iOS and Android both and built-in Alarm clock apps. I haven't used Windows in years so I do not recall if Windows has one or not. I know there are lots of offline Alarm clock apps, but if I understand your question you want something that syncs to all devices so if you change a setting on Android it'll apply to the settings of the app you have on your iPad correct?

Comment: Correct, @MichaelSchwartz

Comment: If you dont need the snooze function (apparently you need something that guarantee that disabling the sound is difficult enough that you will be awake), there something I used to do that i think is better.
Install any alarm on your laptop, connect it to a loud speaker (a Bluetooth one will make difficult that you just pull the audio cord) and lock your session with a password. A really long one.
Just set the laptop to not hibernate so the alarm don't fail, and the torture is guaranteed :)

Comment: Is it necessary that the app has 1 alarm or multiple alarms? Also do you want the alarms at a specific time or just set it to sleep on 6 hours instead of alarm at 7 am?

Comment: @Jedi You know what? If I don't see an answer here in 1 week, I will build that app myself! 
It should be simple enough and I actually need it, so I have two great reasons to make it.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/jeSmhIx.jpeg

Answer (score 0):

A CalDAV task with an attached reminder provides this, if you install the client software on each device to facilitate it, of course.

I set mine via [the Tasks.org Android application](https://tasks.org/) or [my Nextcloud instance](https://wim.nl.tab.digital) with the [Tasks app](https://apps.nextcloud.com/apps/tasks) installed, which where they are stored. I use DAVx5 to synchronize them between my server and tasks app of my choice on my Android device.

[image]

For the less technical, [Google Tasks](https://support.google.com/tasks/answer/7675772) or [Microsoft To-Do](https://todo.microsoft.com) should also work for this. However, note that To-Do is not yet supported by Tasks.org, so you'll have to use its luckily [cross-platform 1st-party apps](https://todo.microsoft.com/tasks/#:%7E:text=Learn%20more-,download%20to%20do,-Terms%20of%20use) and/or [website](https://to-do.live.com/tasks/).

Ensure that you exclude the applications from your Windows 10/11 Focus Assist and Android Do Not Disturb lists.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community, what additional information? It's a very simple question, and I provided an unnecessarily cited answer. In fact, I was unable to add more citations because this website stated that I had reached the allowed limit of hyperlinks per post for a new user.

Answer (score 0):

I use [**Sleep as Android: Smart Alarm**](https://sleep.urbandroid.org/).

It detects when you fall asleep using your smartwatch or, in its absence, sounds. You can set up how much sleep you want and if it should wake you in the middle of REM sleep etc.

The alarms can be configured to not stop unless you solve a puzzle, etc. For example,

[image]

A few other alarm settings

[image]

However, note that this only synchronizes between Android devices.